# Unit tests for a Redshift wrapper class

Tags: python, object-oriented, python-3.x, unit-testing, amazon-web-services

I'm somewhat new to TDD and unit testing, but I've written a suite of unit tests to check my functionality.  The basic classes automate simple load and unload operations from s3 and redshift, and allow one to use custom SQL if needed.  I've also implemented an `execute` method which will try an operation on a dev database first, so that if there is a failure it never touches production.

Here are my classes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
A sub-module of the inst_utils module, this module deals directly with tasks
relating to Amazon Web Services objects.
"""
import logging
from os import path
import sys

import boto3
import psycopg2 as ppg2

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] - %(message)s')


class S3Loads(object):
    def __init__(self, infile, s3_destination, s3_bucket, s3_credentials):
        """
        This class automates the upload of a file to AWS S3.

        :param infile: A gzipped csv file
        :param s3_destination: The path to the desired folder on S3.  The file
        will be named by joining the s3_destination and the infile name.
        :param s3_bucket: The name of the bucket that

        :return: None, but will write out to logging file.
        """
        self.infile = infile
        self.s3_destination = path.join(s3_destination, infile.split('/')[-1])
        self.bucket_name = s3_bucket
        self.s3_creds = s3_credentials

    @staticmethod
    def create_s3_session(s3_creds):
        """
        Expects a dictionary with the access key, secret access key, and
        region.  Dictionary keys must be named as in the example below.

        Ex:
        S3_INFO = {
        'aws_access_key_id': S3_ACCESS,
        'aws_secret_access_key': S3_SECRET,
        'region_name': 'us-west-2'
        }

        :return: returns an S3 resource object.
        """
        session = boto3.session.Session(**s3_creds)
        return session.resource('s3')

    @staticmethod
    def set_session_bucket(session, bucket_name):
        """
        Creates an S3 Bucket object using an authorized session.

        :param session: Expects an S3 resource object that has been
        pre-authorized.
        :param bucket_name: The name of the bucket as it appears in the AWS
         management console.

        :return: Returns an S3 Bucket object.
        """
        return session.Bucket(bucket_name)

    @staticmethod
    def unload_to_s3(database_credentials,
                     table_name,
                     unload_url,
                     s3_credentials):
        """
        Unloads the data from a Redshift table into a specified location in S3.

        :param database_credentials: A dictionary containing the host, port,
        database name, username, and password.  Keys must match example:

        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO = {
            'host': REDSHIFT_HOST,
            'port': REDSHIFT_PORT,
            'database': REDSHIFT_DATABASE_DEV,
            'user': REDSHIFT_USER,
            'password': REDSHIFT_PASS
        }

        :param table_name: The Redshift table name.  Must include the schema if that
        is required for database access. Ex: 'schema.table'
        :param unload_url: The bucket destination on S3 where the data will
        be unloaded.
        :param s3_credentials: A dictionary containing the access and
        secret access keys.  Keys must match the example:

        S3_INFO = {
        'aws_access_key_id': S3_ACCESS,
        'aws_secret_access_key': S3_SECRET,
        'region_name': 'us-west-2'
        }

        :return: None
        """
        s3_access = s3_credentials['aws_access_key_id']
        s3_secret = s3_credentials['aws_secret_access_key']

        try:
            with ppg2.connect(**database_credentials) as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()
                unload = '''
                UNLOAD ('SELECT * FROM {table}')
                TO '{destination}'
                CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={pub};aws_secret_access_key={priv}'
                MANIFEST
                DELIMITER '|'
                GZIP
                ALLOWOVERWRITE
                '''.format(
                    table=table_name,
                    destination=unload_url,
                    pub=s3_access,
                    priv=s3_secret)

                logging.info('Unloading from {table}'.format(table=table_name))
                cur.execute(unload)
                conn.commit()

        except ppg2.Error as e:
            logging.critical('Error occurred during unload: {error}'.format(
                error=e
            ))
            sys.exit(1)

    @staticmethod
    def upload_to_bucket(bucket, filename, destination):
        """

        :param bucket: An S3 Bucket object.
        :param filename: The gzipped file name.  If a full path is given, takes
        only the last portion by splitting on '/'.
        :param destination: The path on the AWS server.  See example:

        'jira/issue_components/format-2014-08-18/'

        :return: None
        """
        logging.info('Uploading {} to {}'.format(filename, destination))
        bucket.upload_file(filename, destination)

    def load(self):
        self.session = self.create_s3_session(self.s3_creds)
        self.bucket = self.set_session_bucket(self.session, self.bucket_name)
        self.upload_to_bucket(self.bucket, self.infile, self.s3_destination)
        logging.info('\nS3 upload was a success.\n')


class RedshiftBase(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 s3_credentials,
                 redshift_db_credentials,
                 table_name=None,
                 schema_name=None,
                 manifest_url=None,
                 unload_url=None,
                 dev_db_credentials=None,
                 sql_stmt=None,
                 safe_load=False,
                 truncate=False):
        """
        This class abstracts common interactions between S3 and Redshift
        databases, including operations such as copy and unload.  It offers
        the ability to execute custom sql statements, and offers the ability
        to do a 'safe load', which is where an operation is first performed
        on a development database (should be identical to its production
        counterpart), and checking for errors before it is allowed to touch
        the production environment.

        :param table_name: The Redshift table name.  Must include the schema if that
        is required for database access. Ex: 'schema.table'.
        :param s3_credentials: A dictionary containing the access and
        secret access keys.  Keys must match the example:

        S3_INFO = {
        'aws_access_key_id': S3_ACCESS,
        'aws_secret_access_key': S3_SECRET,
        'region_name': 'us-west-2'
        }

        :param redshift_db_credentials: A dictionary containing the host, port,
        database name, username, and password.  Keys must match example:

        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO = {
            'host': REDSHIFT_HOST,
            'port': REDSHIFT_PORT,
            'database': REDSHIFT_DATABASE_DEV,
            'user': REDSHIFT_USER,
            'password': REDSHIFT_PASS
        }

        :param schema_name: The schema name associated with the desired table.
        :param unload_url: In the case of an unload operation, this specifies
        the location on S3 where the files will be unloaded to.
        :param manifest_url: The location of the file on S3.
        :param sql_stmt: A SQL statement given as a single string.  This is the
        statement that will be used instead of the default.

        Ex:
        '''
        SELECT *
        FROM table
        WHERE conditions < parameters
        ORDER BY field DESC
        '''

        :param safe_load: If True will trigger a test load to a specified
        development database during the 'execute' method.  Useful for making
        sure the data will correctly load before truncating the production
        database.
        :param truncate: If 'True', the production table will be truncated
        before the operation is executed.

        :return: None
        """
        if schema_name:
            self._table_name = schema_name + '.' + table_name
        else:
            self._table_name = table_name
        self._manifest_url = manifest_url
        self._unload_url = unload_url
        self._s3_credentials = s3_credentials
        self._prod_db_credentials = redshift_db_credentials
        self._dev_db_credentials = dev_db_credentials
        self._sql_stmt = sql_stmt
        self._safe_load = safe_load
        self._truncate = truncate
        self._valid_attribute_names = {
            'table_name': '_table_name',
            'manifest_url': '_manifest_url',
            'unload_url': '_unload_url',
            's3_credentials': '_s3_credentials',
            'dev_db_credentials': '_dev_db_credentials',
            'prod_db_credentials': '_prod_db_credentials',
            'safe_load': '_safe_load',
            'truncate': '_truncate'
        }

    def __repr__(self):
        return ('Table: {table}\nManifest URL: {manifest}\nUnload URL: '
                '{unload}\nS3 Credentials: {s3_creds}\nDev DB Credentials: '
                '{dev_db}\nProd DB Credentials: {prod_db}\nSafe Load: '
                '{safe_load}\nTruncate: {truncate}'.format(
            table=self._table_name,
            manifest=self._manifest_url,
            unload=self._unload_url,
            s3_creds=self._s3_credentials,
            dev_db=self._dev_db_credentials,
            prod_db=self._prod_db_credentials,
            safe_load=self._safe_load,
            truncate=self._truncate
        ))


class RedshiftLoads(RedshiftBase):
    def change_attrs(self, new_attributes):
        """
        Changes the specified instance attributes to new values.

        :param new_attributes: A sequence (or sequence of sequences) that
        contains the name and new values (name, new_value)

        :return: None
        """

        for attr_name, new_val in new_attributes:
            if attr_name not in self._valid_attribute_names:
                raise AttributeError('Must be one of the following values: '
                                     '{attrs}'.format(
                    attrs=self._valid_attribute_names.keys()))
            else:
                self_method = self._valid_attribute_names.get(attr_name)
                setattr(self, self_method, new_val)

    @staticmethod
    def copy_to_db(database_credentials,
                   table_name,
                   manifest_url,
                   s3_credentials,
                   truncate=False):
        """
        Copies data from a file on S3 to a Redshift table.  Data must be
        properly formatted and in the right order, etc...

        :param database_credentials: A dictionary containing the host, port,
        database name, username, and password.  Keys must match example:

        REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO = {
            'host': REDSHIFT_HOST,
            'port': REDSHIFT_PORT,
            'database': REDSHIFT_DATABASE_DEV,
            'user': REDSHIFT_USER,
            'password': REDSHIFT_PASS
        }

        :param table_name: The Redshift table name.  Must include the schema if that
        is required for database access. Ex: 'schema.table'.
        :param manifest_url: The location of the file on the S3 server.
        :param s3_credentials: A dictionary containing the access and
        secret access keys.  Keys must match the example:

        S3_INFO = {
        'aws_access_key_id': S3_ACCESS,
        'aws_secret_access_key': S3_SECRET,
        'region_name': 'us-west-2'
        }

        :param truncate: If 'True', will cause the table to be truncated before
        the load.

        :return: None
        """
        s3_access = s3_credentials['aws_access_key_id']
        s3_secret = s3_credentials['aws_secret_access_key']

        logging.info('Accessing {table}'.format(table=table_name))
        try:
            with ppg2.connect(**database_credentials) as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()

                if truncate:
                    RedshiftLoads.truncate_table(table_name, cur)

                load = '''
                COPY {table}
                FROM '{manifest}'
                CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id={pub};aws_secret_access_key={priv}'
                DELIMITER '|'
                GZIP
                TRIMBLANKS
                TRUNCATECOLUMNS
                ACCEPTINVCHARS
                TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
                DATEFORMAT 'auto'
                MANIFEST
                '''.format(
                    table=table_name,
                    manifest=manifest_url,
                    pub=s3_access,
                    priv=s3_secret)
                logging.info('Copying to {table}'.format(
                    table=table_name))
                cur.execute(load)
                conn.commit()
                logging.info('Copy complete.')
        except ppg2.Error as e:
            logging.critical('Error occurred during load: {error}'.format(
                error=e
            ))
            sys.exit(1)

    def execute(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._safe_load:
            if not self._dev_db_credentials:
                raise AttributeError(
                    'For a safe load to be performed a development database '
                    'must be provided.'
                )
            logging.info('Test operation triggered.')
            method(
                database_credentials=self._dev_db_credentials, *args, **kwargs)
            logging.info('Test operation on the development database was a '
                         'success.')
        logging.info('Commencing operation on the production database')
        method(
            database_credentials=self._prod_db_credentials, *args, **kwargs)
        logging.info('Operation on the production database was a success.')

    def get_attr(self, attribute):
        """Returns the current value of a specified instance attribute."""
        if attribute not in self._valid_attribute_names:
            raise AttributeError('Attribute not found.  Must be one of the '
                                 'following: {attrs}'.format(
                self._valid_attribute_names))
        else:
            attr_name = self._valid_attribute_names[attribute]
        return getattr(self, attr_name)

    @staticmethod
    def truncate_table(table, cursor):
        """
        Truncates a table given the fully qualified table name."""
        logging.info('Truncating {table}'.format(table=table))
        try:
            trunc_stmt = '''
            truncate table {}
            '''.format(table)

            cursor.execute(trunc_stmt)
        except ppg2.Error as e:
            logging.critical('Error occurred during truncation: '
                             '{error)'.format(error=e))
            sys.exit(1)

    def use_custom_sql(self, sql, database_credentials=None):
        """Accepts a custom sql statement and executes it."""
        logging.info('Executing custom sql query: {query}'.format(
            query=sql
        ))
        if not database_credentials:
            database_credentials = self._prod_db_credentials
        try:
            with ppg2.connect(**database_credentials) as conn:
                cur = conn.cursor()
                cur.execute(sql)
                conn.commit()
        except ppg2.Error as e:
            logging.critical('Error occurred during load: {error}'.format(
                error=e
            ))
            sys.exit(1)
```

And here are my unit tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
Unit tests for the aws module
"""
from datetime import datetime
import psycopg2 as ppg2
import unittest

import boto3

from inst_config import config3
from inst_utils import aws


class AWSLoads(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.conn_dev = ppg2.connect(**config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO)
        self.conn_prod = ppg2.connect(**config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO_PROD)
        self.cur_dev = self.conn_dev.cursor()
        self.cur_prod = self.conn_prod.cursor()
        self.rs = aws.RedshiftLoads(
            s3_credentials=config3.S3_INFO,
            redshift_db_credentials=config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO_PROD,
            dev_db_credentials=config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO,
            table_name='dev_test',
            schema_name='ods_tests',
            safe_load=True,
            truncate=True
        )
        self.rs.truncate_table(self.rs._table_name, self.cur_dev)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.rs.truncate_table(self.rs._table_name, self.cur_dev)
        self.conn_dev.close()
        self.conn_prod.close()

    def test_can_change_attrs_and_retrieve_values(self):
        rs = aws.RedshiftLoads('s3_credentials', 'db_credentials')
        new_attrs = (
            ('table_name', 'Test Table'),
            ('manifest_url', 'Test Manifest'),
            ('unload_url', 'Test Unload'),
            ('s3_credentials', 'Test S3'),
            ('dev_db_credentials', 'Test Dev DB'),
            ('prod_db_credentials', 'Test Prod DB'),
            ('safe_load', False),
            ('truncate', False)
        )
        rs.change_attrs(new_attrs)
        for attr_name, val in new_attrs:
            self.assertEqual(rs.get_attr(attr_name), val)

    def test_can_execute_custom_sql(self):
        timestamp = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
        select = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM {}
        '''.format(self.rs._table_name)
        self.rs.truncate_table(self.rs._table_name, self.cur_dev)
        res_dev = self.cur_dev.execute(select)
        self.assertEqual(res_dev, None)

        sql = '''
        INSERT INTO {}
        VALUES ('Hello', 1, '{}')
        '''.format(self.rs._table_name, timestamp)
        self.rs.use_custom_sql(
            sql=sql, database_credentials=self.rs._dev_db_credentials
        )
        self.cur_dev.execute(select)
        res = self.cur_dev.fetchall()
        self.assertEqual(res, [('Hello', 1, timestamp)])

    def test_can_unload_from_s3(self):
        timestamp = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
        sql = '''
        INSERT INTO {}
        VALUES ('Hello', 1, '{}')
        '''.format(self.rs._table_name, timestamp)
        self.cur_dev.execute(sql)
        self.conn_dev.commit()

        aws.S3Loads.unload_to_s3(
            database_credentials=config3.REDSHIFT_POSTGRES_INFO,
            table_name=self.rs._table_name,
            unload_url=('s3://' +
                        config3.S3_BUCKET +
                        '/unittests/aws_unit_tests.txt'),
            s3_credentials=config3.S3_INFO
        )
        client = boto3.client('s3')
        resp = client.get_object(
            Bucket=config3.S3_BUCKET,
            Key='unittests/aws_unit_tests.txt0000_part_00.gz'
        )
        self.assertTrue(resp)

    def test_can_copy_to_redshift(self):
        self.rs.copy_to_db(
            database_credentials=self.rs._dev_db_credentials,
            table_name=self.rs._table_name,
            manifest_url=('s3://' +
                          config3.S3_BUCKET +
                          '/unittests/aws_unit_tests.txt' +
                          'manifest'),
            s3_credentials=config3.S3_INFO,
            truncate=True
        )

        sql = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM {}
        '''.format(self.rs._table_name)
        self.cur_dev.execute(sql)
        res = self.cur_dev.fetchall()
        self.assertTrue(res)

    def test_can_execute_safe_load_custom_sql(self):
        timestamp = datetime(2000, 1, 1)
        select = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM {}
        '''.format(self.rs._table_name)
        self.rs.truncate_table(self.rs._table_name, self.cur_dev)
        self.rs.truncate_table(self.rs._table_name, self.cur_prod)
        res_dev = self.cur_dev.execute(select)
        res_prod = self.cur_prod.execute(select)
        self.assertEqual(res_dev, res_prod)

        sql = '''
        INSERT INTO {}
        VALUES ('Hello', 1, '{}')
        '''.format(self.rs._table_name, timestamp)
        self.rs.execute(aws.RedshiftLoads.use_custom_sql, self, sql=sql)

        self.cur_dev.execute(select)
        self.cur_prod.execute(select)
        res_dev = self.cur_dev.fetchall()
        res_prod = self.cur_prod.fetchall()
        self.assertEqual(res_dev, res_prod)
        self.assertTrue(res_prod)

    def test_can_execute_safe_load_copy_to_db(self):
        self.rs.execute(
            aws.RedshiftLoads.copy_to_db,
            table_name=self.rs._table_name,
            manifest_url=('s3://' +
                          config3.S3_BUCKET +
                          '/unittests/aws_unit_tests.txt' +
                          'manifest'),
            s3_credentials=config3.S3_INFO,
            truncate=True
            )

        select = '''
        SELECT *
        FROM {}
        '''.format(self.rs._table_name)
        self.cur_dev.execute(select)
        res_dev = self.cur_dev.fetchall()
        self.cur_prod.execute(select)
        res_prod = self.cur_prod.fetchall()
        self.assertEqual(res_dev, res_prod)
        self.assertTrue(res_dev)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Any feedback or helpful critiques either on the main classes, or the unittests is much appreciated!